# NodeJS and Nginx - How to open url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I am trying to open url using using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open). It works locally, but if I try to use the same thing on my deployed app, it is not working, it just skip that part, or it looks like that because it returns a message, but it is not opening url. Is there something that should be configured on server for this?

For example, I am trying to do this

```html
        const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: scopes,
        });
        try {
            opn(authorizeUrl, { wait: true }).then(cp => {
                console.log('cp', cp)
                const server = http
                    .createServer(async (req, res) => {
                        try {
                            if (req.url.indexOf('/callback') > -1) {
                                const qs = new url.URL(req.url, `${process.env.SERVER_API_URL}`)
                                    .searchParams;
                                res.end(
                                    'Authentication successful! Please return to the console.'
                                );
                                server.destroy();
                                const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(qs.get('code'));
                                oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
                                resolve(oAuth2Client);
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            reject(e);
                        }
                    })
            });
            return res.send({ msg: 'okay' })
```

and it works locally, but on deployed app it just returns 'ok'. If I use callback or something else to return message, it just block and causes timeout.

Comment: are you handling the promise returned by the response?

Comment: Yes, but it just won't open it, or do anything.

Comment: may be your deployment environment has firewall rules to not allow outging http requests ?

Comment: No, I checked. Everything is fine. And still not opening :/

Comment: add more code may be the function in which you are calling `open` to better understand the context

Comment: I have edited post.

Comment: FYI: if function return promise it make no sens to use try..catch use `.catch(fn)` and if your open function throw exeception it should not do that and return `Promise.reject()`

Comment: Your async function is not waiting for the callback to finish, you need to wrap callback inside a promise. But I have another question: why are you starting a new http server in this code? It will not receive any requests in this instance I think

Comment: I tried to do that, no working. Can you please show how would you rewrite it? Maybe I am not doing it correctly. Also, it bugs me because it is working locally, no problems..